# Failed to create the right pattern to extract the desired portion from a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

What would be the right pattern if I applied regex to the following string:

```
item = "JavaScript:muestra('01','043','071','01','600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR')"
```

and the result I wish to get is:

```
0104307101600-2023-SUNARP-TR
```

I've tried with:

```
import re

item = "JavaScript:muestra('01','043','071','01','600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR')"
content = re.findall(r"(\('.+?'\))",item)[0].replace("'","").replace(",","")
print(content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> import re
>>> item = "JavaScript:muestra('01','043','071','01','600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR')"
>>> chunks = re.findall(r"'([^']+)'", item)
>>> chunks
['01', '043', '071', '01', '600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR']
>>> chunks[-1]
'600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR'
```

If this feels too "loose", you can first grab the parenthesized area with something like:

```py
paren = re.search(r"\(([^)]+)\)", item)
```

or, more precisely:

```py
paren = re.search(r"JavaScript:muestra\(([^)]+)\)", item)
```

then run the `'`-based match in the top snippet.

Using `re.split()` can also work:

```py
[x for x in re.split(r"'(?:,')?", paren[1]) if x]
```

Another approach is `ast.literal_eval` to convert the parenthesized substring into a tuple:

```py
>>> import ast
>>> paren = re.search(r"\([^)]+\)", item)
>>> ast.literal_eval(paren[0])
('01', '043', '071', '01', '600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR')
>>> tup = ast.literal_eval(paren[0])
>>> tup[-1]
'600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR'
```

Boiling this down to a one-liner without regex:

```py
>>> ast.literal_eval(item.replace("JavaScript:muestra", ""))[-1]
'600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR'
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote

item = "JavaScript:muestra('01','043','071','01','600%2D2023%2DSUNARP%2DTR')"

data = ''.join(
    unquote(item).split('(')[-1].strip('()').replace('\'','').split(',')
)
print(data) # 0104307101600-2023-SUNARP-TR
```